# Can we efficiently count modulo 2 the number of connected subgraphs of a planar graph?

Tags: graph-theory, polynomials

[Paper p.9](https://iuuk.mff.cuni.cz/~andrew/Tutte.pdf) and Wikipedia 
relate the Tutte polynomial of a graph to another polynomial.

If $(x-1)(y-1)=z$, $$T(G;x,y)=F_G(z,y)/H(G)$$

Where $F_G(z,y)=\sum_{A \subseteq E}z^{c(G_A)}(y-1)^{|A|} $
where $c(G)$ is the number of connected components and $H(G)$ has simple
closed form. $F_G(z,2)$ is polynomial in $z$ and the coefficient of $C$ of $z$
is the number of connected **spanning** subgraphs of $G$.
The constant coefficient of $F_G(z,2)$ is zero.

So $$F_G(z,2) \mod z^2= Cz=T(G;z+1,2) H(G) \mod z^2 \qquad (1)$$

If $G$ is planar, $T(G;x,y)$ is efficiently computable for $z=2$
which gives the RHS of (1).

Setting $z=2$ we get: $2C \mod 4 =2 T(G,3,2)=\rm{known}$, which allows finding
$C \mod 2$.

> Will this approach work?

I reproduce the polynomial relation in sagemath after help on MSE.